# hammer.js detect variables in panmove and unbind when it hits certain criteria

Tags: hammer.js

my goal is detect when an element has reached a certain margin-left, and than unbind or stop the panmove from continuing if it hits that threshold. 
I have a "panmove" bound to an element using hammer.js, and jquery hammer plugin. 
I noticed that in the panmove, console.log(e) will fire hundreds of times as you move the elements, which is expected. If you however put an if statement in the panmove function, it only goes off of the initial state of the first panmove and not the current one.

```
.bind("panmove", function (e) {
    var count = 0;
    console.log(e);
    console.log(count++);
    var _this = $(e.target);
    var _thisDataLeft = _this.attr("data-left");
    var _thisDataMaxLeft = _this.attr("data-maxleft"); // this is derived from the width of the Delete box, which can be any width. 
    if (Math.abs(_thisDataLeft) < Number(_thisDataMaxLeft)) {
        _this.css({ left: Number(_thisDataLeft) + e.gesture.deltaX }); // controls movement of top layer
        console.log(count++);
    }
```

I noticed that the console.log(count++) always fires 1, instead of iterating up, as if it is only reading it once in the beginning. 
How can I run an if statement inside of this Pan, so that it is always the current information, and not just the first iteration?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up moving away from Hammer.js, was not able to get the results I needed. It looks like the more basic jquery.event.move.js was easier to use than hammer.

here is my example in js fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/williamhowley/o9uvo50y/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // http://stephband.info/jquery.event.move/
    // http://stephband.info/jquery.event.swipe/
    // add swipe functionality to the rows.
    // I think you will need to add the swipe left, after it is activated by a HOLD down press. 
    // idk, how do you always make something swipable. 

    var wrap = $('ul#main');


    $('ul#main > li')
    .on('movestart', function (e) {
        console.log("move start");

        // var $li = $(e.target).closest('.swipable'); // this would be normal live integration
        var $li = $(e.target);
        if ($li.attr("data-hasplaceholder") !== "true") { // if it does not have a placeholder, add one.
            createBackgroundSpacer($li);
            $li.attr("data-hasplaceholder", true); // signify that a placeholder has been created for this element already. 
        }

        // If the movestart heads off in a upwards or downwards
        // direction, prevent it so that the browser scrolls normally.
        if ((e.distX > e.distY && e.distX < -e.distY) ||
            (e.distX < e.distY && e.distX > -e.distY)) {
            e.preventDefault();
            return;
        }

        // To allow the slide to keep step with the finger,
        // temporarily disable transitions.
        wrap.addClass('notransition'); // add this to the container wrapper. 
    })
    .on('move', function (e) {
        // event definitions
        // startX : 184, where from left the mouse curser started.
        // deltaX: ?
        // distX: how far the mouse has moved, if negative moving left. Still need to account for double movement, currently can only handle one movement. 

        console.log("move");
        console.log(e);

        var maxLeft = $('.rightContent').width();
        var marginLeftNum = Number($(this).css('margin-left').replace(/[^-\d\.]/g, ''));

        if (marginLeftNum <= -maxLeft && e.deltaX < 0) { // Case when user is at outermost left threshold, and trying to move farther left.  
            $(this).css({ 'margin-left': -maxLeft });
        }
        else if (marginLeftNum == -maxLeft && e.deltaX > 0) { // When user is at threshold, and trying to move back right. 
            $(this).css({ 'margin-left': marginLeftNum + e.deltaX });
        }
        else if (e.target.offsetLeft>=0 && e.deltaX>0) { // If the offset is 0 or more, and the user is scrolling right (which is a positive delta, than limit the element. )
            $(this).css({ 'margin-left': 0 });
        }
         // Must have a Negative offset, and e.deltaX is Negative so it is moving left. 
        else if (e.deltaX < 0) { // Case when element is at 0, and mouse movement is going left. 
            $(this).css({ 'margin-left': marginLeftNum + e.deltaX }); 
        }
        else {  // Moving Right when not on 0
            $(this).css({ 'margin-left': marginLeftNum + e.deltaX });
        }



    })
    .on('swipeleft', function (e) {
        console.log("swipeleft");
    })
    .on('activate', function (e) {
        // not seeing this activate go off, i think this is custom function we can add on if swipe left hits a threshold or something. 
        console.log("activate");
    })
    .on('moveend', function (e) {
        console.log("move end");
        wrap.removeClass('notransition');
     });



    var createBackgroundSpacer = function ($shoppingListRow) {
        var border = 2;

        $shoppingListRow.css({ 'width': $shoppingListRow.width() + border, 'height': $shoppingListRow.height() + border });  // gives itself set width and height
        $shoppingListRow.addClass('swipable');

        // placeholder HTML
        var leftPlaceholder = $('<div class="leftPlaceholder"></div>').css({ 'height': $shoppingListRow.height()});
        var rightPlaceholder = $('<div class="rightPlaceholder"></div>')
        var rightContent = $('<div class="rightContent">Delete</div>').css({ 'height': $shoppingListRow.height()});
        rightPlaceholder.append(rightContent);
        var placeHolder = $('<div class="swipePlaceholder clearfix"></div>'); // goes around the two floats. 
        placeHolder.css({ 'width': $shoppingListRow.width(), 'height': $shoppingListRow.height() });
        placeHolder.append(leftPlaceholder, rightPlaceholder);

        $shoppingListRow.before(placeHolder); // adds placeholder before the row.
        $shoppingListRow.css({ 'marginTop': -($shoppingListRow.height() + border) });
    };

});
```